# How to query count with 0 rows

Tags: sql-server

My query is to get the count of total rows, along with the columns.  An example table, which has to be a temp table is:

## temp(a1,a2)

I need to query a1,a2, and total number of rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalRow, a1, a2 from #temp group by a1,a2
```

The query works fine for table with rows >=1.  However, for some special case, this table has zero row. In that case, `TotalRow` does not return a value (it should be zero).  How can I get that query work for all cases including zero row?  Thanks.

Comment: If table has zero row, which value you want to put in a1 and a2?

Comment: @JoeTaras I would imagine `NULL`s would do it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need zero for TotalRow, and nulls for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I would look COALESCE or ISNULL functions, which can return "zero" if null:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd resolve this with two query:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) from #temp > 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalRow, a1, a2 from #temp group by a1,a2
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 0 as TotalRow, NULL as a1, NULL as a2
END
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  That query will be used in the Crystal report.   As you know, Crystal report only use the first query when I use stored procedure to do it.  If I have the zero for the totalrow, and null for the

Comment: @user1816353: and you can't call an SP and its result is managed by C.R.?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get all combinations of `a1` and `a2`, even when there are no rows, then try this:

```
select a1.a1, a2.a2, count(t.a1) as TotalRow
from (select distinct a1 from #temp) a1 cross join
     (select distinct a2 from #temp) a2 left outer join
     #temp t
     on a1.a1 = t.a1 and a2.a2 = t.a2
group by a1, a2;
```